# How to determine precisely which libpath a loaded library has come from?

Tags: r

Suppose `length(.libPaths())` > 1. R will look for any library in the first path, if it can't find it there, then in the second, and so on until it finds it. If it can't find a library of that name in any of the `libPaths()`, it errors with `there is no package called ‘library_name’`

We can see the currently loaded packages with `sessionInfo()`

How can I tell precisely which `libPaths()` a particular library has loaded from?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

We're dealing with computers, so it is predictable :)  And there is a rule:  First match on `.libPaths()` wins.

```
R> .libPaths()
[1] "/usr/local/lib/R/site-library" "/usr/lib/R/site-library"      
[3] "/usr/lib/R/library"           
R> IP <- installed.packages()
R> IP[IP[,"Package"]=="Rcpp", ]
                                             Package 
                                              "Rcpp" 
                                             LibPath 
                     "/usr/local/lib/R/site-library" 
                                             Version 
                                           "1.0.4.6" 
                                            Priority 
                                                  NA 
                                             Depends 
                                                  NA 
                                             Imports 
                                    "methods, utils" 
                                           LinkingTo 
                                                  NA 
                                            Suggests 
"tinytest, inline, rbenchmark, pkgKitten (>= 0.1.2)" 
                                            Enhances 
                                                  NA 
                                             License 
                                        "GPL (>= 2)" 
                                     License_is_FOSS 
                                                  NA 
                               License_restricts_use 
                                                  NA 
                                             OS_type 
                                                  NA 
                                              MD5sum 
                                                  NA 
                                    NeedsCompilation 
                                               "yes" 
                                               Built 
                                             "4.0.0" 
R>
```

So here we see that *e.g.* `Rcpp` comes from the first location. `installed.packages()` will, as I recall, return multiple as--in case you have a package in multiple places (as *e.g.* user library and system library).

Comment: Great info. If I understand correctly, we can always assume that the location that a package has loaded from will *always* be the first of `libPaths()` in which that package is found?

Comment: Correct. (That actually bit me in the tail the other day when I tested reverse-depends and the to-be-tested version was shadowed by an older one in a 'just for the test' temp library that ... comes before it in the `.libPaths()`.  No warning.  Just loads the 'bad' one.  Defensible for efficiency reason but I still had a lot of scrambled egg on my face...)